# How to create hierarchy of ktor clients

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

Coming from Okhttp, I'm used to creating multiple instances of the http client, where each "inherits" behavior from the parent one (and adding own behavior), by calling `okHttpClient.newBuilder()` (which is better than just sharing setup, as it shared the threadpools etc if possible)

How to do the same with ktor client?

I notice there is `install(httpClient: HttpClient)` which seems like what I want, but turns out the the otherway around (it applies "this" behavior to the client argument)

I want to inherit parent client behavior when configuring the child one

Or is this not idiomatic in ktor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HttpClient.config](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client/-http-client/config.html) method creates a new `HttpClient` instance with a provided configuration based on an existing client configuration.
Also, you can create a new engine configuration based on an existing one using the [HttpClientEngineFactory.config](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.engine/config.html) method.